# Smoothing/blending a joint between two meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm modeling a car, but I don't want to add any polygons. I don't need to (I'm trying to have a nicer mesh) so I've got two separate pieces here. Unfortunately this doesn't give me the curved effect, as in the picture below.

I was thinking to fix this in a normal map, but I'm sure I've seen tools for doing this specific thing, and I just can't recall how I saw it done (whether it was in a texture map or not).

I wasn't really big on the solutions, I did find for this here.

[image: model top, picture bottom]

Here's a picture of the wireframe. 
[image]

I could model this, I just don't want to do it that way, I'm sure there's an alternate way.

Comment: hello, you don't give enough details, how is your mesh in wireframe mode, what part are you trying to do and can't, etc?

Comment: I told you about these new users. This is the reason why I need to remind them to vote for the answer....

Comment: @moonboots Here's a picture of the wireframe https://i.imgur.com/CsHuDWv.png I could model this I just don't want to do it that way, I'm sure there's an alternate way

Comment: I'm afraid you have no choice but to do it with one mesh

Comment: @moonboots I suppose I can always make this piece a plug in MeshMachine when it comes to 2.8 https://youtu.be/2DpjEHxjh2s?t=61 To be honest I hadn't considered the solution when I made this post D:

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I can make this piece into a 'plug' with MeshMachine and place it on my mesh with the additional smoothing in the corner modeled onto that plug.

Example https://youtu.be/2DpjEHxjh2s?t=61

Just waiting for the 2.8 version